# Opposite of "mute" or "silence" as verb

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms

If I said

> I **silenced** him during our online conversation

or

> I **muted** the television

what would I use to indicate the reverse event occurred? I've seen *unmute* used in various contexts, but it's [not](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unmute) a real word.

Comment: @Rob Hruska: We don't need a special word for every possible thing we can do. You could perhaps just *reinstate* him. In context that would be obvious, surely?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - *Reinstate* would probably work, although I'm still interested in whether or not there's something more specific. *Reinstate* implies that there's a known context (that a muting previously occurred), and would be non-deterministic if multiple events had happened that could all be reinstated.

Comment: @Rob Hruska: Well my point is precisely that there *won't* be a word. Just because you now mute stuff online doesn't mean it's a new concept. We've had mute buttons on tv remotes for decades, and they're used by everyone everywhere. If we needed a word, we'd have found or coined it decades ago.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - *"Hey, can you reinstate the television? I can't hear it."* sounds pretty awkward :). But I'll accept the fact that a specific word doesn't exist - I was mainly wondering if it did. My searches had proven fruitless, and I don't claim to know every word in existence, so I thought I might ask here.

Comment: I have to balk at the notion that a word is "not a real word" if it's not in the dictionary.

Comment: @Rob Hruska: I didn't mean in every context. Suppose you watch a film on tv with someone else, and they have the remote. They mute it during a commercial break, you chat together for a few minutes, then *you* notice that the adverts are finishing, and it's time to watch/listen again. What do you say? Me, I'd just say **Turn it back**, or **Put the sound back on**, or something. I certainly wouldn't *unmute* it. But you can say whatever you like, I guess. I don't really see the need for a one-word term - and nor do most tv watchers, apparently.

Comment: Unmute is indeed a valid word, but I wish there were a special word for it, as "unmute" feels like a double negative.  Phrases like "while the loudspeaker is unmuted" feel strange to me.  "[Non-inverting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Non-inverting_amplifier)" bothers me in the same way, but I can't think of any synonym with the same meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For televisions and similar appliances *[unmute](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unmute)* is an acceptable word that is in common usage.

For *silence* meaning *subdue* I would choose *encourage* as an antonym .

Comment: *Unmute* is precisely the right word in any situation, formal or informal, where it reverses a previous muting; televisions, computers, phones, or any place where *mute* is the appropriate verb for silencing the source of the sound.

Comment: @Matthew Frederick, yes I agree I will edit the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Despite what your dictionary might say (or not say),

**unmute**

is a perfectly acceptable word to describe that action. There are many combinations of affixes that are productive on many roots which just aren't mentioned in word lists.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, there won't be a special word. So many people watch tv with others, there's only one remote. We'd all be using it if there was such a word.

**reinstate** is a single-word that could sometimes be used.

In the context of the tv scenario, I'd just say **put it back**, or **turn the sound back on**, or something. I certainly wouldn't **unmute** it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Some dictionary not listing a word does not mean that it is "not a real word". There's no dictionary police waiting to come and get you once you use it. (Or is there?)

Prefixing stuff (yep, verbs, nouns, adjectives, you name it) with un- appears to be very productive in English. Hence, "unmute" is a good candidate. Even "unsilence" should work.

After all, you'd need to (methodically) ask a lot of (different) native speakers to find out whether any of those two is marked. Otherwise, any descent online dictionary should provide you with one or more cross-referenced antonyms for "to mute" or "to silence".

Comment: The dictionary police *are* watching you, not is.  This is your last warning, citizen.

Comment: Watching you watching them

Answer (score 0):

The opposite to *mute* as in sound control is often marked as "undo", which seems much better than *unmute*.

Comment: Better if you include some references to definition and also some usage examples.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft uses "unmute" in their Skype documentation:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Mute-or-unmute-audio-in-a-Skype-for-Business-Lync-Meeting-or-call-94f12302-dc95-44ba-8792-c43e115b3d26

Answer (score 0):

"Undo" is not common in the world of professional sound control, except perhaps in the relatively recent domain of computerized music. For decades it was often heard in professional audio circles to "UNMUTE" a channel, following the muting of mixing console channel. I wholeheartedly believe it to be the perfect word to reverse "mute".

Answer (score -1):

**Vocalize**

I know using "vocalize" in this context is a little weird, but this might be the most suitable word I can think of.

> I silenced him during our online conversation.
>
> I vocalized him after 5 minutes.

Or

> I made him vocalized after 5 minutes.

**Sound**

> I sounded him 5 minutes later.

Comment: You would vocalize a thought but not a person.

Comment: Agree, how about sound?

Comment: Um, I'm not feeling that one either http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sound?rskey=XjgqCE&result=1#m_en_gb0793560